# How do I keep an Azure WebJob from exiting without using JostHost or Azure Storage Account?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs

I'm in the process of setting up an Azure WebJob that continuously does stuff for me but I'm having trouble preventing it from exiting.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{   
   //Some other code/work

   JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration();
   config.DashboardConnectionString = null;
   new JobHost(config).RunAndBlock();       
}
```

As you can see I'm currently trying to use the JobHost.RunAndBlock() method to prevent my job from exiting. Assume "Some other code/work" returns control to the caller immediately but does require the application to keep running later on.

The use of JobHost requires me to set up an Azure Storage account because it wants to log stuff using the AzureWebJobsStorage connection string. However I do not want to use this feature for logging my stuff, I'm merely want my application to keep running and I do not want to create an Azure Storage account.

So what code could I use to prevent my code from exiting if I do not want to create an Azure Storage Account or the JobHost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way (and a very simple example) of keeping a WebJob alive without the `JobHost` is to have a continuous loop in there:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{   
   //Some other code/work

    while (true)
    {
        Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
        //or
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Based on what should be the trigger of the functionality, you could check for the time / messages / work to be done / whatever inside that while loop and trigger the work when necessary.

Further improvements could be to check if cancellation is needed and exit the loop gracefully if it is.